# How do I uninstall Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I installed a VS 2013 trial on my Windows 10 PC. Now the trial period has expired and I want to remove it. However I can not find it listed under Control Panel->Programs->Programs and Features!?

Comment: Are you sure it's not under a different name? Besides, why use a VS2013 trial when VS2015 Pro is free as the Community edition?

Answer (score 8):

1. Search `C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\` for `vs_*.exe` and you should see one or more bootstrap installers named for the version, E.g. `vs_enterprise.exe`, `vs_community.exe`
2. Run the executable with the `/uninstall` command line.

Alternatively run the original installer again in the hopes that it offers an uninstall option, if not reinstall it in the hopes it fixes the missing link.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the [Visual Studio Uninstaller](https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller). Its a tool developed by Microsoft and should get rid of the Visual Studio Instance.